# (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) Tomcat+OpenSSL

Tags: linux, tomcat, openssl

I am trying to enable SSL in my Tomcat.
But when I start Tomcat and go to https://localhost:8443 I see

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

To do that I used CA.sh to generate private key and signed certificate like this:

```
progerlaptop:/usr/share/ssl/misc # ./CA.sh -newca
CA certificate filename (or enter to create)

Making CA certificate ...
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
................................++++++
.............................................++++++
writing new private key to './demoCA/private/./cakey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase: pass
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase: pass
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:UK
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Chernihiv
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Chernihiv
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:University
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:student
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:localhost
Email Address []:proger@localhost

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
Using configuration from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for ./demoCA/private/./cakey.pem:
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
Certificate Details:
        Serial Number:
            c6:55:7e:58:1b:4d:9c:7e
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 25 13:17:31 2010 GMT
            Not After : Nov 24 13:17:31 2013 GMT
        Subject:
            countryName               = UK
            stateOrProvinceName       = Chernihiv
            organizationName          = University
            organizationalUnitName    = student
            commonName                = localhost
            emailAddress              = proger@localhost
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                C7:98:1E:68:A7:3A:C4:B2:46:C8:88:99:C8:D5:CA:66:D3:94:23:66
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C7:98:1E:68:A7:3A:C4:B2:46:C8:88:99:C8:D5:CA:66:D3:94:23:66

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
Certificate is to be certified until Nov 24 13:17:31 2013 GMT (1095 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
progerlaptop:/usr/share/ssl/misc # ./CA.sh -newreq
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
............++++++
.........................++++++
writing new private key to 'newkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase: pass
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase: pass
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:UK
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Chernihiv
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Chernihiv
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:University
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:student
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:localhost
Email Address []:proger@localhost

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
Request is in newreq.pem, private key is in newkey.pem

progerlaptop:/usr/share/ssl/misc # CA.sh -sign
Using configuration from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem: pass
...
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y
...
Signed certificate is in newcert.pem
```

Copied key and cert in to my Tomcat directory.

```
cp newcert.pem newkey.pem /path/to/tomcat-6.0.29/ssl/
```

Added Connector to my server.xml:

```
   <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
      maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
      enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
      acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" 
      SSLEngine="on". 
      SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/ssl/newcert.pem" 
      SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/ssl/newkey.pem". 
      SSLPassword="pass"/>
```

Then I start catalina.sh run.
And when I go to https://localhost:8443/ I see this nasty error.
When I do I do wrong? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat 6 and above? You need to set the SSLEnabled="true", as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339835/ssl-error-in-ubuntu-and-tomcat) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240885/ssl-servlet-implementation-issue-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-p).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you should have the keystore file in you machine

Make sure in the  server.xml file and also refer this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#SSL_and_Tomcat) it could be helpful for you to solve

```
     <Connector port=”8443” maxHttpHeaderSize=”8192″
      maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
      enableLookups=”false” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
      acceptCount=”100″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
      **keystoreFile=”/../../../Tomcat/mycert.jks”**
      clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by changing a **port** value. The value 443 was reserved, so I put 1443, restart Tomcat and it worked.

My `Connector` is:

```
<Connector port="1443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="D:/path_to_ca.jks" 
    keystorePass="somePass" />
```

Now the URL is:

https://localhost:1443/index.jsp

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using APR/OpenSSL for https, in which case SSLEngine="on" is correct.

Did you install libtcnative?

Assuming tomcat 6: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Quick steps:

```
tar zxf tomcat-native-1.1.20-src.tar.gz
cd tomcat-native-1.1.20-src/jni/native/
./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-ssl=yes
make && make install
cd /usr/java/default/jre/lib/amd64/
ln -s /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so
```

When you start tomcat you have to see this line in your catalina.out:

```
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.20.
```

The alternative is to use JSSE and add your certificates/keys to a java keystore (.keystore file).  I find the java keystore a pain in the arse to use so I usually go with APR.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by adding `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` to the connector