# SEVERE: error registering connector Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat5.5

I've try to deploy my project with Tomcat 5.5 (sounds dull :D)

But i have a trouble when using SSL with this error like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240885/ssl-servlet-implementation-issue-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-p).

> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:7080.
>
> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

And later i go and fix it with this post with [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/543154/Tomcat/connect-https-localhost) with adding `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"`  into my Connector tag in my tomcat `server.xml`. But when i restart my tomcat, there is an error like this image (dont know how to copy this error through windows terminal)

[image]

And this is my `server.xml` connector tag

```
<Connector  port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           sslEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/keystores/keystore_lipsweb_jetty.jks"
           keystorePass="jetty1" />
<Connector port="7080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Well, i still have no idea how to fix this. Really appreciate with your helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been resolve this problem by change my Tomcat version. When i create this post, i use Tomcat 5.5.36. But when i try to use an older one (5.5.26), There is no error on deployment and my project working properly.

Well, so far i don't know what the difference between Tomcat 5.5.36 and 5.5.26. I hope in few times i can explain what happen here in detail. But anyone who knows this thing can sharing here and i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this and it worked for me

```
 <Connector className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector" port="80" minProcessors="5"
                   address="10.1.0.50"
                   maxProcessors="75"
                   enableLookups="false" redirectPort="443" acceptCount="10" debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000"
                   useURIValidationHack="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   address="10.1.0.50"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
                   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEnabled="true"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   keystoreFile="/usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/keystore.jks"
                   keystorePass="password"/>
```

Comment: CMIIW, what should i do is just add that className property into my connector? is that it?

Comment: just copy it in your http connector not the https one

Comment: I did it, but nothing change. Still error `(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)`

Comment: can you show me how the configurations looks like after adding the class name

Comment: it's just like configuration i've posted, just added `className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"` after `keyStoresPass` property. is it true?

Comment: no you need to put the class in the connector with port Connecto 7080

Comment: can you replace yor connectors with my connectors and modify it to your configuration  i think this will be better

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake. Ya i mean i've put after `URIEncoding` property in 7080 connector and nothing changed at all.

Comment: does the org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector jar file exists ?? if not download it from http://mavenhub.com/c/org/apache/coyote/tomcat4/coyoteconnector/jar and you need to put it under lib if its not already there

Comment: i've been download and put tomcat4-coyote-4.1.36 into common->lib and copy your configuration into `server.xml`. when i start my tomcat, it said `error initializing endpoint, socket bind failed`

Comment: this means that something esle is using the port can you make sure that the ports which you are using are not used by other services or change the ports for faster results

Comment: Hm, honestly i dont know how to fix it. Ok, i'll try to find it out.